# Serverless Azure SQL - databases per server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

As you can see in the screenshot below, a **server** needs to be selected or created in order to create an azure sql serverless database.

Can I reuse that **server** and create other azure sql serverless databases on it? If so, **how many databases can be created using the same server?**

[image: Azure sql database configuration]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the documentation:

[Azure SQL Logical Server Limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/resource-limits-logical-server?view=azuresql)

It's 5000 databases per logical server.